# Inserting contact works on emulator, but not on physical device (Sony Xperia C6603)

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, sony-xperia

I use an emulator with Android 5.1.1 and a Sony device with same OS version.
The code used(source: developer.android.com):

```
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import static android.R.attr.accountType;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
    values.put(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "hello");
    Uri rawContactUri = getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);
    long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);

    values.clear();
    values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
    values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Mike Sullivan");
    getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
}
```

the Manifest contains both `READ_CONTACTS and WRITE_CONTACTS` permissions

Code works well in an emulator, but on Sony device the contact does not show up. There is no exception or anything and the filter is set to show all contacts (local, google etc.). I found a similar topic where someone stated a ContactContracts problem with Sony device but he was at least able to see a name, I don't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try running both operations (insert **RawContact** and insert **Data** to it) in a batch, like this:

```
 ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
      .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "hello")
      .build());

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
      .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
      .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Mike Sullivan")
      .build());

 getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```